# SQL error 1215 unable to add foreign key

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, innodb

I am unable to add a simple foreign key to my table. I have previously been able to add foreign keys but only of INT or BIGINT type. I am trying to make this of type VARCHAR and am receiving a 1215 error with description unable to add foreign key constraint.

Command that causes failure:

```
 ALTER TABLE `TradingAccount` 
 ADD CONSTRAINT `email`
   FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`)
   REFERENCES `User` (`email`)
   ON DELETE NO ACTION
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Both owner_id and email are of datatype VARCHAR(255).

I am using MySQL Workbench and feel there is some misconfiguration that does not allow me to use varchar for foreign key constraint? Do I need to setup mysqlworkbench to use INNODB or is that default.

Any help would be great, cheers.

Comment: The datatypes have to be identical, so you will have to refer a varchar to a varchar (which the owner id probably is not).

Comment: owner_id and email are both of type varchar(255)

Comment: Can you add the table description of both tables (`show create table user`, `show create table TradingAccount`? If you want, you can remove all unused columns, but have to leave every index/key in `User` in it (you may not have an index on `email` there).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that TradingAccount.owner_id and/or OwnerMaster.owner_id are not exactly the same data type as TradingAccount.owner_id and OwnerMaster.owner_id.

Comment: Both are varchar(255)